# android orientation change with savedInstanceState and retrieveInstanceState for signup page

Tags: android, orientation

I am new to android, love to learn..

I am just building a basic application which has a login page and sign up page. I want to add orientation change with the data saved from portrait to landscape.

Kindly suggest to me some code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow here you can ask question which should have required some efforts from your side too.But what you are asking is like too many questions/requirements so you need to start step by step thats my suggestion. so please refer the http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html link and came up with some efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manifest file add below code within the activity tag

`<activity
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
/>`

Comment: thank u. Am done with this problem:)

Comment: if it worked for you then mark it

Answer (score 0):

Just save key, value pairs in onSaveInstanceState() and retrieve it in onCreate().

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            value1 = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY1);
            value2 = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY2);
            value3 = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY3);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(KEY1, value1);
        outState.putString(KEY2, value2);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY3,  value3);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```